# Failed to set new theme

Tags: themes, lightdm

When I try to login into the system, I am getting the error `failed to set new theme`

```
failed to write file '/var/lib/lightdim/.cache/xfce4-notifyd-theme.rc.D5AWOY':write() failed ; no space left on device
```

please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: This looks like your partition is filled up. Try to login on console and delete old files from `/var/log` and maybe `/tmp`. Depending on your partition layout. `df -hTa` might help...

Comment: No sir even through there is lot of space on device

Comment: If you are able to login as root, that should be possible as normally root has reserved space. Otherwise you have to boot a live system, mount your partition(s) and free space.

Comment: Yep , i solved this problem , by somehow the directory was fulled with lots of log files , so i logged in as  super user and deleted the files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Akshay's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832497/failed-to-set-new-theme/1178641#comment1288547_832497), the directory was filled with lots of log files. Logging in as superuser and deleting the files solved the problem.